# Struts 2 includeProperties does not work, but root does for json result type

Tags: json, struts2

I am posting this because I have found by googling another person who had the same problem but no resolution was mentioned.  It is on another help site, so i don't know what the policy is about posting such links is, but I have it available if need be.

So my problem is like this:

```
    <action name="CountQuery" class="info.pureshasta.action.QueryAction" method="countQuery">
           <result name="success" type="json">
             <param name="root">
                countResults
             </param>
           </result>
           <result name="input">SetupQuery</result>     
    </action>
```

does exactly what I want it to.  Namely, it returns a JSON object containing ONLY the `countResults` (which happens to be an Integer) attribute.  Reading the [plugin documentation](http://://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/json-plugin.html) I would think that includeProperties would be what i want, especially if I end up wanting two attributes instead of one attribute in my JSON object.  My attempt at this is like so:

```
        <action name="CountQuery" class="info.pureshasta.action.QueryAction" method="countQuery">
           <result name="success" type="json">
             <param name="includeProperties">
                countResults
             </param>
           </result>
           <result name="input">SetupQuery</result>     
    </action>
```

Anyone know of any circumstances where this would be the case?  Am I missing a prefix for `countResults` in the latter case?  What happens when I run my app with the latter case is I get all the attributes which are associated with my Action instead of just the one I want.

Comment: What you are doing looks correct, you'll need to provide more information to expose the error, add the action class, the string you are using to invoke the action and the jsp.  It wouldn't hurt for you to add the struts2-config-browswer-plugin if you haven't so you can see what struts2 believes is configured. You should definitely not get all the attributes, you should get 'countResults' or nothing.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem with struts 2.2.3. What version of struts and json plugin are you using?

Comment: Ok, back in front of code, I can look at the comments.  @doctrey Looking at my project, I am using struts2-core-2.2.1.1 and struts2-json-plugin-2.2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I turn on my computer this morning, restore root to includeProperties, and the darn thing works don't you know.  My output in javascript land is

`{"countResults", 10078467}`

and I have double checked and triple checked and my struts.xml snippet above is exactly the same.

Just for any future readers, when I use root instead of includeProperties I get

```
10078467
```

and I guess that is the expected behavior in each case.  Until I need more attributes, root actually works better for me because I can use the value directly instead of having to look it up in the json object (save 1 step, how lazy!)

So I guess it turns out to be a caching issue?  I have noticed that the web app is sluggish to show the changes when I have been working with the jquery / struts2/ json combination over the past day.

Comment: Yes that might have been the problem. I think setting parameter `noCache` to `true` could help, although it doesn't guarantee since caching is browser-dependent.

Comment: Just for background: When you set root to countResults it is countResults that gets serialized thus producing 10078467. Generally it is the action which is serialized into JSON, which is why you see the names.  With the include/exclude properties you trim down the class properties which will be serialized.